# show / hide previous element with jquery

Tags: jquery

OK, this should in theory be simple, but I've tried several things like `parent`, `parentsUntil`, `next` and more, and haven't been able to figure it out.

I've got several `div`s as shown below, each with a hidden and a visible image, and two visible buttons. when you hover over a button, it should show or hide the image that is shown / hidden.

```
<div class="quarterWidth boxShadow">
    <h2>category</h2>
    <img src="image.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="xyz" class="normalPic">
    <img src="other.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="xyz" class="hoverPic">
    <p class="button button180"><a class="trad" href="#">Traditional</a></p>
    <p class="button button180"><a class="contemp" href="#">Contemporary</a></p>
</div>
```

I have hidden the `.hoverPic` with jQuery successfully, and when I hover over the `a.contemp` button, I want the `.normalPic` image to hide, and the `.hoverPic` to show, and the opposite would happen when you hover over `.trad`.

**How on earth would you achieve this with jQuery? Here is my pitiful attempt:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.hoverPic').hide();

    $('.contemp').hover(function(){
        $(this).parentsUntil('.boxShadow').next('.normalPic').hide();
        $(this).parentsUntil('.boxShadow').next('.hoverPic').show();
    });

    $('.trad').hover(function(){
        $(this).parentsUntil('.boxShadow').next('.normalPic').show();
        $(this).parentsUntil('.boxShadow').next('.hoverPic').hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: use `.prev()` I think should help, :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd use `.closest()` to find the parent `div` and then use that as a context to find the relevant images:

```
$(function() {
    $('.hoverPic').hide();

    $('.contemp').hover(function(){
        var $parent = $(this).closest("DIV");
        $('.normalPic', $parent).hide();
        $('.hoverPic', $parent).show();
    });

    $('.trad').hover(function(){
        var $parent = $(this).closest("DIV");
        $('.normalPic', $parent).show();
        $('.hoverPic', $parent).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$('.contemp').hover(function(){
    $(this)
        .closest('.boxShadow')
        .children('.normalPic').hide().end()
        .children('.hoverPic').show();
});

$('.trad').hover(function(){
    $(this)
        .closest('.boxShadow')
        .children('.normalPic').show().end()
        .children('.hoverPic').hide();
});
```

This will find the closest ancestor with class `.boxShadow` and from there finds its children `.normalPic` and `.hoverPic` and changes their visibility. Note how you can use method chaining to avoid searching for the same elements over and over again.

Also note that the same function will be called when you leave the element. Instead of `hover`, you might just want to use `mouseenter`.

---

Without repeating code, but maybe less intuitive:

```
$('.contemp, .trad').mouseenter(function(){
    var is_contemp = $(this).hasClass('contemp');
    $(this)
        .closest('.boxShadow')
        .children('.normalPic').toggle(!is_contemp).end()
        .children('.hoverPic').toggle(is_contemp);
});
```

---

**Reference:** [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/), [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)

Comment: You're welcome :) Btw, you should accept some more of your previous question if they have been helpful.